# OData Web API without EF (Entity Framework)

Tags: rest, odata, powerbi, t4

after lot of search, do not found any good and concise information which does not use the EF and still implement the OData standard. For example: [Create an OData v4 Endpoint Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)

very well described with EF.

**Does anyone have good source without using EF.** *(I was more interested into using the t4 template custom tool, generated dto classes etc.)*

my ultimate goal is to use OData api in Power BI OData feed which must have the OData standard and not using EF(Entity Framework)

although it seems that there are couple of duplicate but none of them have enough info.

Comment: where does your data live?  Power Bi can pull from so many different data sources, you should not have to write an ODATA endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for response. data are stored in mysql and there are few services written (not exposed only used in our application only) which return some json data and that is used to tabular report. Now there is requirement to get the same data to Power BI. I want to use the Odata Feed but not with EF.

Comment: Is the requirement to see the same data in tabular in Power Bi or rolled up / summarized?

Comment: not necessarily. They just want the same data as existing report. they might use it to create more graphical information